# mysqli bind param function

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my SQL.

```
$sql = "SELECT updates.update_id, models.model_id, first_name, last_name, updates_models.update_id, updates_models.model_id
FROM updates, models, updates_models
WHERE updates.update_id = updates_models.update_id AND models.model_id = updates_models.model_id AND updates.update_id = $names";
```

I am attempting to use the `$stmt->bind_param();` function

In the $sql above would I be correct thinking there are 3 values that I need to pass to the `$stmt->bind_param()`?

Like this

```
$sql = "SELECT updates.update_id, models.model_id, first_name, last_name, updates_models.update_id, updates_models.model_id
FROM updates, models, updates_models
WHERE updates.update_id = ? AND models.model_id = ? AND updates.update_id = ?";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,
your external variable is only $names, so your select will be

`$sql = "SELECT updates.update_id, models.model_id, first_name, last_name, updates_models.update_id, updates_models.model_id FROM updates, models, updates_models WHERE updates.update_id = updates_models.update_id AND models.model_id = updates_models.model_id AND updates.update_id = ?";`

Comment: Eagle eyes! Good catch!